# insert value into random row

Tags: pandas, random

I have a dataframe as below.

```
D1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [15, 22, 107, 120],
                   'b': [25, 21, 95, 110]})
```

I am trying to randomly add two rows into column 'b' to get the effect of below. In each case the inserted 0 in this case shifts the rows down one.

```
D1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [15, 22, 107, 120, 0, 0],
                   'b': [0, 25, 21, 0, 95, 110]})
```

Everything I have seen is about inserting into the whole column as opposed to individual rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one potential way to achieve this using [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) and [`numpy.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
import numpy as np

n = 2
rand_idx = np.random.randint(0, len(D1), size=n)

# Append 'n' rows of zeroes to D1
D2 = D1.append(pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((n, D1.shape[1])), columns=D1.columns, dtype=int), ignore_index=True)

# Insert n zeroes into random indices and assign back to column 'b'
D2['b'] = np.insert(D1['b'].values, rand_idx, 0)
print(D2)

     a    b
0   15   25
1   22    0
2  107    0
3  120   21
4    0   95
5    0  110
```

Comment: This is excellent..!! if there was a double vote option i would have . :)

Comment: @anky_91 very kind of you, really appreciate that :)

Comment: Thanks very much for this. really elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html#numpy.insert) with set positions - for `a` by random and for `b` by length of original `DataFrame`:

```
n = 2
new = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)
a = np.insert(D1['b'].values, len(D1), new)
b = np.insert(D1['a'].values, np.random.randint(0, len(D1), size=n), new)

#python 0.24+
#a = np.insert(D1['b'].to_numpy(), len(D1), new)
#b = np.insert(D1['a'].to_numpy(), np.random.randint(0, len(D1), size=n), new)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b': b})
print (df)
     a    b
0   25    0
1   21   15
2   95   22
3  110    0
4    0  107
5    0  120
```